# URL Decoding for cURL

Tags: web-services, curl

I have a web service with a UI; however, I'm trying to automate some things using cURL from a batch file. If I use

```
start /wait curl -k GET "http://localhost:8080/MY/WEBService/start?runImmediatelyStr=TRUE&pathToTestStr=folder\script.vbs&parametersStr=param1=value1"
```

with only one parameter (param1) everything works fine. I got this by using the UI and then copying the URL after filling out a certain form and submitting. Here is the URL that I copied.

```
http://localhost:8080/MY/WEBService/start?runImmediatelyStr=TRUE&delayStr=&dateScheduledStr=&notificationListStr=&pathToTestStr=folder%5Cscript.vbs&parametersStr=param1+%3D+value1
```

the only differences between the URL I copied and the URL in the cURL command being the `%5C` which I replaced with `\` and the `+%3D+` which I replaced with = (spaces are trimmed in webservice so they don't matter anyway).

How can I decode

```
http://localhost:8080/MY/WEBService/start?runImmediatelyStr=TRUE&delayStr=&dateScheduledStr=&notificationListStr=&pathToTestStr=folder%5Cscript.vbs&parametersStr=param1+%3D+value1%0D%0Aparam2+%3D+value2
```

so that I can use the `start /wait curl -k GET "URL"`? I think specifically I'm looking to replace %0D%0A, but I'm so new to webservices and cURL that I really have no idea. I've been searching Google and SO, but can't seem to find anything. I've tried `--data-urlencode`, but that wasn't fruitful.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: To save my eyes, please stop using -X superfluously...

Comment: Remove the -X, check!